# How can I start nostromo webserver?

Tags: http, webserver

I'm trying to launch nostromo webserver(http://nazgul.ch/dev_nostromo.html). After compilation I make some changes in config. But when I'm trying to start "nhttpd" - nothing happens. Could anyone know how to use it, I haven't found any guides.
Here is my config:

```
# MAIN [MANDATORY]

servername      localhost:80

serverlisten        127.0.0.1
serveradmin     root@localhost
serverroot      /var/nostromo
servermimes     conf/mimes
docroot         /var/nostromo/htdocs
docindex        index.html

# LOGS [OPTIONAL]

logpid          logs/nhttpd.pid
logaccess       logs/access_log

# SETUID [RECOMMENDED]

user            root

# BASIC AUTHENTICATION [OPTIONAL]

#htaccess       .htaccess
#htpasswd       /var/nostromo/conf/.htpasswd
#htpasswd       +bsdauth
#htpasswd       +bsdauthnossl

# SSL [OPTIONAL]

#sslport        443
#sslcert        /etc/ssl/server.crt
#sslcertkey     /etc/ssl/private/server.key

# CUSTOM RESPONSES [OPTIONAL]
#
# The custom responses are searched in the corresponding document root.


# ALIASES [OPTIONAL]

/icons          /var/nostromo/icons

# VIRTUAL HOSTS [OPTIONAL]


# HOMEDIRS [OPTIONAL]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# MAIN [MANDATORY]

servername              127.0.0.1:8080
serverlisten            *
serveradmin             webmaster@nazgul.ch
serverroot              /var/nostromo
servermimes             conf/mimes
docroot                 /var/nostromo/htdocs
docindex                index.html

# LOGS [OPTIONAL]

logpid                  logs/nhttpd.pid
logaccess               logs/access_log

# SETUID [RECOMMENDED]

user                    daemon

# ALIASES [OPTIONAL]

/icons                  /var/nostromo/icons
```

I have my config file like this. The ***user*** option cannot be root. My system is CentOS, so the web daemon user is called daemon. On Debian, it would be www-data.

In addition, you may need to *chmod* the /var/nostromo/logs directory with all permissions (777).

Then, depending on your system, you start the server as a non-root user with sudo privileges like so:

```
$ sudo nhttpd
```

or

```
$ sudo /usr/local/sbin/nhttpd
```

If you try to enable IPv6 with the ***-4*** flag, it will complain.

I tried various combinations of these steps and doing all of them was the only way it worked for me. I don't know why this is the case, but it is what it is.

For reference, this is written for nhttpd v1.9.6.